# Atualizar tabela de acordo com a quantidade de coluna

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

A tabela de cadastro não foi modelada corretamente, porém preciso fazer um UPDATE por SQL para realizar esta importação, segue exemplo:

Veja que os filhos de Bomi Bulsara, precisam ficar em [nomeDoDependente1] e o outro em [nomeDoDependente2], sei que é possível mas ainda possuo uma grande dificuldade com SQL, poderiam me ajudar?

A tabela possui até quatro colunas com os dependentes e a **tabela de dependentes** que precisa ser importada precisa identificar os demais dependentes e ir inserido nos próximas colunas, exemplo: se possui 3 dependentes então irar inserir em dependente1, dependente2, e dependente3**

Tabela atual:

```
IDDoFuncionario - nomeDoFuncionario - nomeDoDependente1  - nomeDoDependente2  
12              - Joseph Jackson    - [nomeDoDependente] - [nomeDoDependente]  
13              - Bomi Bulsara      - [nomeDoDependente] - [****************]
```

Dados para atualizar a "Tabela atual":

Tabela de dependente

```
IDDoFuncionario - nomeDoDependente
12              - Michael Jackson   
12              - Janet Jackson  
13              - Fred Mercury
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando a "Tabela atual" = `Table1` e "Tabela de dependente" = `Table2`

A seguinte consulta faz a *"trasposição"* dos dados para serem inseridos.

```
SELECT
    IDDoFuncionario,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1) AS nomeDoDependente1,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS nomeDoDependente2,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) AS nomeDoDependente3,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3) AS nomeDoDependente4
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

Então é só inserir esse `SELECT` em um `UPDATE` assim:

```
UPDATE Table1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    IDDoFuncionario,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1) AS nomeDoDependente1,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS nomeDoDependente2,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) AS nomeDoDependente3,
    (SELECT nomeDoDependente FROM Table2 WHERE T1.IDDoFuncionario = Table2.IDDoFuncionario LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3) AS nomeDoDependente4
  FROM Table1 AS T1
) AS q ON q.IDDoFuncionario = Table1.IDDoFuncionario
SET
  Table1.nomeDoDependente1 = q.nomeDoDependente1,
  Table1.nomeDoDependente2 = q.nomeDoDependente2,
  Table1.nomeDoDependente3 = q.nomeDoDependente3,
  Table1.nomeDoDependente4 = q.nomeDoDependente4;
```

Comment: Danilo, não funcionou, vou colocar uma linha aqui pois tem limite de caracteres:
<pre><code> SELECT ID, (SELECT PAR00NOME FROM PEN_CADASTRO WHERE T1.ID = pen_cadastro_funcionarios_importados.ID LIMIT 1) AS nomeDoDependente1, FROM PEN_CADASTRO AS T1 </code></pre>

Comment: @rock.ownar fiz [esse fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78bef/2) e funcionou direitinho la

Comment: Danilo, descobri o que eu estava errando é no alias que não especifiquei, muito obrigado cara!!!
Outra coisa aonde tu aprendeu banco?

Comment: A maior parte do que aprendi foi montando meus bancos de dados e buscando as repostas para minhas perguntas em fóruns online como esse.

Comment: Ahhh muito obrigado man... agradeço tu ajudou pakas se nem imagina rs

Answer (score 0):

Faça um SQL do tipo :

```
select IDDoFuncionario , nomeDoFuncionario , 1 codigoDoDependente , nomeDoDependente1 nomeDoDependente
from tabela_atual
union all
select IDDoFuncionario , nomeDoFuncionario , 2 codigoDoDependente , nomeDoDependente2 nomeDoDependente
from tabela_atual
union all
select IDDoFuncionario , nomeDoFuncionario , 3 codigoDoDependente , nomeDoDependente3 nomeDoDependente
from tabela_atual
```

desta forma a tabela fica "unpivoteada" e fica fácil inserir em uma tabela normalizada